# How to make SSM Document shared between all AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-ssm

I am working on AWS system manager.I am using this to push my software to the instances using distributor which is under system manager.

The distributor creates one package.The package will have my installation script,uninstallation script and the .exe file which I am gonna push.This whole package will save as a SSM document which is maintained by system manager.

My problem if suppose I have two AWS accounts:

**A account** - The account where I created a package(us-east-1)

**B account** - The Instance which is running.(ap-southeast-2

I want to push the package in 'A' to account 'B' Instance.

I have to do this with my python code.So I used boto3.

```
 def runcommand(self,instanceid):
        try:
            response = self.ssmclient.send_command(
                InstanceIds=[instanceid,],
                DocumentName='AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage',
                TimeoutSeconds=600,
                Parameters={
                    'action': ['Install'],
                    'installationType':['Uninstall and reinstall'],
                    'name':['arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:accnumber:document/SSMDistributorPackage']
                },
                OutputS3Region='ap-southeast-2',
                OutputS3BucketName='output',
                OutputS3KeyPrefix='abcd',
            )
            print("Successfully pushed the agent....")
        except Exception as e:
            print("The error while running command:::::",str(e))
        print("response(send_command)::::",response)
```

But it throws error like **Invalid Document:cross region arn is not supporting**.

How can I solve this?

**Is there anyway to make this package supported by all aws accounts?**

Answer (score 2):

SSM Documents can be [shared across accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-sharing.html).

However, this error is not a cross account error. Its that you are referencing an SSM Document from one region to another region.

As the client and instance is in `ap-southeast-2` but the document is in `us-east-1` you will need to create the document in the `ap-southeast-2` region.

Comment: I modified my document permission type to share already.But I don't know why this alert is throwing

Comment: Which region is your ssm client?

Comment: It is at sydney region

Comment: And you're referencing a document in `us-east-1`, you can only reference documents in the same region as you I am afraid :(

Comment: Is there any other way i could solve this in AWS? i want to push my software to the instance

Comment: Assuming your EC2 instances are in the Sydney region, you'll need to create an SSM document in Sydney in either account. I'd suggest that you look at creating the SSM document as infrastructure as code with tool like CloudFormation or Terraform.

Comment: Thank you mokugo-devops for your response and suggestion.I'll try

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215413/discussion-between-codebuff-and-mokugo-devops).